# XSL looping is not occurring properly at each level

Tags: loops, xslt, unique

I need to loop though this SAP IDOC to report shipment data.  I need to break at each change of E2EDT37_KDMAT (part number), E2EDT37_VHILM_KU (package type) and E2EDT37_QUANTITY in the G07 node (PACKAGE).  The current code seemed to work until there was  more than one G16 (DELIVERY) node within a G01 (SHIPMENT) node.

This snippet of code doesn't produce XML output and the issue is seen in the message output.

I believe the method I am trying is just not valid and I will find another way.  But I don't understand why exactly.  I've tried preceding-sibling instead of preceding and just got different wrong output.

Each loop uses the same predicate as the last with one more criterion added to identify all matching the E2EDT37 records and perform the next statement once for each unique value of E2EDT37_KDMAT, E2EDT37_VHILM_KU and lastly E2EDT37_QUANTITY.  It seems to come so close but never gets it right.  What is my misunderstanding of the way E2EDT37_KDMAT[not(.=preceding::E2EDT37_KDMAT)] works here?

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.1"   xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"  
                                            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                                            xmlns:XmlTransform="java:de.axway.converter.xml.xsltextensions.XsltExtensions" exclude-result-prefixes="XmlTransform xsl exsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="/ACTIS">
        <xsl:message></xsl:message>
        <xsl:call-template name="DESADV_D96A"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="DESADV_D96A">
        <xsl:for-each select="//G16">
            <xsl:variable name="current-delivery" select="E2EDL20/E2EDL20_VBELN "/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="/ACTIS/G01/G07[@PACK_TYPE='OUTER']/E2EDT37[contains(E2EDT37_DELIVERIES, $current-delivery)]">
                    <xsl:call-template name="Create_Outer_PAC">
                        <xsl:with-param name="current-delivery" select=" $current-delivery "/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="Create_Outer_PAC">
        <xsl:param name="current-delivery"/>

        <xsl:message>In Create_Outer_PACK Delivery: <xsl:value-of select="$current-delivery"/></xsl:message>

        <xsl:for-each select="/ACTIS/G01/G07/E2EDT37[E2EDT37_PACK_TYPE='OUTER'][contains(E2EDT37_DELIVERIES, $current-delivery)]">
            <xsl:variable name="Pallet" select="current()"/>

            <xsl:message>For each Outer_PAC : <xsl:value-of select="$Pallet/E2EDT37_EXIDV"/></xsl:message>

            <xsl:for-each select="/ACTIS/G01/G07/E2EDT37[E2EDT37_PACK_TYPE='INNER'][E2EDT37_PARENT=$Pallet/E2EDT37_EXIDV][E2EDT37_DELIVERY=$current-delivery]/E2EDT37_KDMAT[not(.=preceding::E2EDT37_KDMAT)]">
                <xsl:variable name="current-part" select="current()"/>

                <xsl:message>For each E2EDT37_KDMAT : <xsl:value-of select="$current-part"/></xsl:message>

                <xsl:message select="/ACTIS/G01/G07/E2EDT37[E2EDT37_PACK_TYPE='INNER'][E2EDT37_PARENT=$Pallet/E2EDT37_EXIDV][E2EDT37_DELIVERY=$current-delivery][E2EDT37_KDMAT=$current-part]/E2EDT37_VHILM_KU"/>

                <xsl:for-each select="/ACTIS/G01/G07/E2EDT37[E2EDT37_PACK_TYPE='INNER'][E2EDT37_PARENT=$Pallet/E2EDT37_EXIDV][E2EDT37_DELIVERY=$current-delivery][E2EDT37_KDMAT=$current-part]/E2EDT37_VHILM_KU[not(.=preceding::E2EDT37_VHILM_KU)]">
                    <xsl:variable name="current-vhilm_ku" select="current()"/>

                    <xsl:message>For each E2EDT37_VHILM_KU: <xsl:value-of select="$current-vhilm_ku"/></xsl:message>

                    <xsl:for-each select="/ACTIS/G01/G07/E2EDT37[E2EDT37_PACK_TYPE='INNER'][E2EDT37_PARENT=$Pallet/E2EDT37_EXIDV][E2EDT37_DELIVERY=$current-delivery][E2EDT37_KDMAT=$current-part][E2EDT37_VHILM_KU=$current-vhilm_ku]/E2EDT37_QUANTITY[not(.=preceding::E2EDT37_QUANTITY)]">
                        <xsl:variable name="current-packqty" select="current()"/>
                        <xsl:message></xsl:message>
                        <xsl:message>For each E2EDT37_QUANTITY: <xsl:value-of select="$current-packqty"/></xsl:message>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ACTIS>
   <EDI_DC>
      <EDI_DC_TABNAM>EDI_DC40</EDI_DC_TABNAM>
      <EDI_DC_CREDAT>20190702</EDI_DC_CREDAT>
      <EDI_DC_CRETIM>210325</EDI_DC_CRETIM>
      <EDI_DC_SERIAL>20190702210323</EDI_DC_SERIAL>
   </EDI_DC>
   <G01>
      <E2EDT20>
         <E2EDT20_SEGNAM>E2EDT20002</E2EDT20_SEGNAM>
         <E2EDT20_MANDT>100</E2EDT20_MANDT>
         <E2EDT20_DOCNUM>0000004250699555</E2EDT20_DOCNUM>
         <E2EDT20_SEGNUM>000001</E2EDT20_SEGNUM>
         <E2EDT20_PSGNUM>000000</E2EDT20_PSGNUM>
         <E2EDT20_HLEVEL>01</E2EDT20_HLEVEL>
         <E2EDT20_TKNUM>0049409223</E2EDT20_TKNUM>
      </E2EDT20>
      <G07 PACK_TYPE="INNER" PARENT="505059227" CHILDREN="0" MIXED="0">
         <E2EDT37 PACK_TYPE="INNER" PARENT="505059227" CHILDREN="0" MIXED="0">
            <E2EDT37_SEGNAM>E2EDT37006</E2EDT37_SEGNAM>
            <E2EDT37_MANDT>100</E2EDT37_MANDT>
            <E2EDT37_DOCNUM>0000004250699555</E2EDT37_DOCNUM>
            <E2EDT37_SEGNUM>000044</E2EDT37_SEGNUM>
            <E2EDT37_PSGNUM>000001</E2EDT37_PSGNUM>
            <E2EDT37_HLEVEL>02</E2EDT37_HLEVEL>
            <E2EDT37_EXIDV>00000000000505755236</E2EDT37_EXIDV>
            <E2EDT37_VHILM_KU>0000SON</E2EDT37_VHILM_KU>
            <E2EDT37_PACK_TYPE>INNER</E2EDT37_PACK_TYPE>
            <E2EDT37_CHILDREN>0</E2EDT37_CHILDREN>
            <E2EDT37_PARENT>505059227</E2EDT37_PARENT>
            <E2EDT37_DELIVERY>0037371519</E2EDT37_DELIVERY>
            <E2EDT37_DELIVERY_POSITION>000010</E2EDT37_DELIVERY_POSITION>
            <E2EDT37_QUANTITY>8500.000</E2EDT37_QUANTITY>
            <E2EDT37_UOM>PCE</E2EDT37_UOM>
            <E2EDT37_KDMAT>6561111</E2EDT37_KDMAT>
            <E2EDT37_VBRST>1000</E2EDT37_VBRST>
         </E2EDT37>
      </G07>
      <G07 PACK_TYPE="INNER" PARENT="505059227" CHILDREN="0" MIXED="0">
         <E2EDT37 PACK_TYPE="INNER" PARENT="505059227" CHILDREN="0" MIXED="0">
            <E2EDT37_SEGNAM>E2EDT37006</E2EDT37_SEGNAM>
            <E2EDT37_MANDT>100</E2EDT37_MANDT>
            <E2EDT37_DOCNUM>0000004250699555</E2EDT37_DOCNUM>
            <E2EDT37_SEGNUM>000047</E2EDT37_SEGNUM>
            <E2EDT37_PSGNUM>000001</E2EDT37_PSGNUM>
            <E2EDT37_HLEVEL>02</E2EDT37_HLEVEL>
            <E2EDT37_EXIDV>00000000000505755237</E2EDT37_EXIDV>
            <E2EDT37_VHILM_KU>0000SON</E2EDT37_VHILM_KU>
            <E2EDT37_PACK_TYPE>INNER</E2EDT37_PACK_TYPE>
            <E2EDT37_CHILDREN>0</E2EDT37_CHILDREN>
            <E2EDT37_PARENT>505059227</E2EDT37_PARENT>
            <E2EDT37_DELIVERY>0037371484</E2EDT37_DELIVERY>
            <E2EDT37_DELIVERY_POSITION>000010</E2EDT37_DELIVERY_POSITION>
            <E2EDT37_QUANTITY>7000.000</E2EDT37_QUANTITY>
            <E2EDT37_UOM>PCE</E2EDT37_UOM>
            <E2EDT37_KDMAT>6561143</E2EDT37_KDMAT>
            <E2EDT37_VBRST>1000</E2EDT37_VBRST>
         </E2EDT37>
      </G07>
      <G07 PACK_TYPE="OUTER" CHILDREN="2" MIXED="1">
         <E2EDT37 PACK_TYPE="OUTER" CHILDREN="2" MIXED="1">
            <E2EDT37_SEGNAM>E2EDT37006</E2EDT37_SEGNAM>
            <E2EDT37_MANDT>100</E2EDT37_MANDT>
            <E2EDT37_DOCNUM>0000004250699555</E2EDT37_DOCNUM>
            <E2EDT37_SEGNUM>000050</E2EDT37_SEGNUM>
            <E2EDT37_PSGNUM>000001</E2EDT37_PSGNUM>
            <E2EDT37_HLEVEL>02</E2EDT37_HLEVEL>
            <E2EDT37_EXIDV>505059227</E2EDT37_EXIDV>
            <E2EDT37_VHILM_KU>0000SON</E2EDT37_VHILM_KU>
            <E2EDT37_CHILDREN>2</E2EDT37_CHILDREN>
            <E2EDT37_CONTENTS>00000000000505755236:00000000000505755237:</E2EDT37_CONTENTS>
            <E2EDT37_PACK_TYPE>OUTER</E2EDT37_PACK_TYPE>
            <E2EDT37_DELIVERIES>0037371519 0037371484</E2EDT37_DELIVERIES>
         </E2EDT37>
      </G07>
      <G16>
         <E2EDL20>
            <E2EDL20_SEGNAM>E2EDL20004</E2EDL20_SEGNAM>
            <E2EDL20_MANDT>100</E2EDL20_MANDT>
            <E2EDL20_DOCNUM>0000004250699555</E2EDL20_DOCNUM>
            <E2EDL20_SEGNUM>000077</E2EDL20_SEGNUM>
            <E2EDL20_PSGNUM>000001</E2EDL20_PSGNUM>
            <E2EDL20_HLEVEL>02</E2EDL20_HLEVEL>
            <E2EDL20_VBELN>0037371484</E2EDL20_VBELN>
            <E2EDL20_VSTEL>0016</E2EDL20_VSTEL>
            <E2EDL20_VKORG>0060</E2EDL20_VKORG>
            <E2EDL20_VKBUR>EUR</E2EDL20_VKBUR>
            <E2EDL20_LGNUM>D16</E2EDL20_LGNUM>
            <E2EDL20_ABLAD>JAG01</E2EDL20_ABLAD>
            <E2EDL20_INCO1>FCA</E2EDL20_INCO1>
            <E2EDL20_INCO2>NÜRNBERG</E2EDL20_INCO2>
            <E2EDL20_ROUTE>DES129</E2EDL20_ROUTE>
            <E2EDL20_VSBED>ST</E2EDL20_VSBED>
            <E2EDL20_BTGEW>107.000</E2EDL20_BTGEW>
            <E2EDL20_NTGEW>107.000</E2EDL20_NTGEW>
            <E2EDL20_GEWEI>KGM</E2EDL20_GEWEI>
            <E2EDL20_VOLUM>1036.427</E2EDL20_VOLUM>
            <E2EDL20_VOLEH>DMQ</E2EDL20_VOLEH>
            <E2EDL20_ANZPK>00000</E2EDL20_ANZPK>
            <E2EDL20_PARID>UNKNOWN</E2EDL20_PARID>
            <E2EDL20_PODAT>20190702</E2EDL20_PODAT>
            <E2EDL20_POTIM>210324</E2EDL20_POTIM>
         </E2EDL20>
         <G29>
            <E2EDL24>
               <E2EDL24_POSNR>000010</E2EDL24_POSNR>
               <E2EDL24_KDMAT>6561143</E2EDL24_KDMAT>
               <E2EDL24_LFIMG>7000.000</E2EDL24_LFIMG>
               <E2EDL24_VRKME>PCE</E2EDL24_VRKME>
               <E2EDL24_VBRST>1000</E2EDL24_VBRST>
               <E2EDL24_KDMAT35>6561143</E2EDL24_KDMAT35>
               <E2EDL24_POSEX>000000</E2EDL24_POSEX>
               <E2EDL24_DELIVERY>0037371484</E2EDL24_DELIVERY>
               <E2EDL24_PO>5500229851</E2EDL24_PO>
               <E2EDL24_PO_DATE>20150612</E2EDL24_PO_DATE>
            </E2EDL24>
         </G29>
         <G29>
            <E2EDL24>
               <E2EDL24_POSNR>900001</E2EDL24_POSNR>
               <E2EDL24_KDMAT>0000SON</E2EDL24_KDMAT>
               <E2EDL24_LFIMG>1.000</E2EDL24_LFIMG>
               <E2EDL24_VRKME>PCE</E2EDL24_VRKME>
               <E2EDL24_VBRST>1000</E2EDL24_VBRST>
               <E2EDL24_KDMAT35>0000SON</E2EDL24_KDMAT35>
               <E2EDL24_POSEX>000000</E2EDL24_POSEX>
               <E2EDL24_DELIVERY>0037371484</E2EDL24_DELIVERY>
            </E2EDL24>
         </G29>
      </G16>
      <G16>
         <E2EDL20>
            <E2EDL20_SEGNAM>E2EDL20004</E2EDL20_SEGNAM>
            <E2EDL20_MANDT>100</E2EDL20_MANDT>
            <E2EDL20_DOCNUM>0000004250699555</E2EDL20_DOCNUM>
            <E2EDL20_SEGNUM>000170</E2EDL20_SEGNUM>
            <E2EDL20_PSGNUM>000001</E2EDL20_PSGNUM>
            <E2EDL20_HLEVEL>02</E2EDL20_HLEVEL>
            <E2EDL20_VBELN>0037371519</E2EDL20_VBELN>
            <E2EDL20_VSTEL>0016</E2EDL20_VSTEL>
            <E2EDL20_VKORG>0060</E2EDL20_VKORG>
            <E2EDL20_VKBUR>EUR</E2EDL20_VKBUR>
            <E2EDL20_LGNUM>D16</E2EDL20_LGNUM>
            <E2EDL20_ABLAD>JAG01</E2EDL20_ABLAD>
            <E2EDL20_INCO1>FCA</E2EDL20_INCO1>
            <E2EDL20_INCO2>NÜRNBERG</E2EDL20_INCO2>
            <E2EDL20_ROUTE>DES129</E2EDL20_ROUTE>
            <E2EDL20_VSBED>ST</E2EDL20_VSBED>
            <E2EDL20_BTGEW>140.600</E2EDL20_BTGEW>
            <E2EDL20_NTGEW>127.500</E2EDL20_NTGEW>
            <E2EDL20_GEWEI>KGM</E2EDL20_GEWEI>
            <E2EDL20_VOLUM>42840.000</E2EDL20_VOLUM>
            <E2EDL20_VOLEH>CMQ</E2EDL20_VOLEH>
            <E2EDL20_ANZPK>00000</E2EDL20_ANZPK>
            <E2EDL20_PARID>UNKNOWN</E2EDL20_PARID>
            <E2EDL20_PODAT>20190702</E2EDL20_PODAT>
            <E2EDL20_POTIM>210325</E2EDL20_POTIM>
         </E2EDL20>
         <G29>
            <E2EDL24>
               <E2EDL24_POSNR>000010</E2EDL24_POSNR>
               <E2EDL24_KDMAT>6561111</E2EDL24_KDMAT>
               <E2EDL24_LFIMG>8500.000</E2EDL24_LFIMG>
               <E2EDL24_VRKME>PCE</E2EDL24_VRKME>
               <E2EDL24_VBRST>1000</E2EDL24_VBRST>
               <E2EDL24_KDMAT35>6561111</E2EDL24_KDMAT35>
               <E2EDL24_POSEX>000000</E2EDL24_POSEX>
               <E2EDL24_DELIVERY>0037371519</E2EDL24_DELIVERY>
               <E2EDL24_PO>5500229848</E2EDL24_PO>
               <E2EDL24_PO_DATE>20150612</E2EDL24_PO_DATE>
            </E2EDL24>
         </G29>
      </G16>
   </G01>
</ACTIS>
```

Resulting Output

1) In Create_Outer_PAC Delivery : 0037371484

2) For each Outer_PAC       : 505059227

3) For each E2EDT37_KDMAT   : 6561143   Good break here at unique KDMAT

I find and display a single matching VHILM_KU here but the next line that tries to loop at each VHILM_KU doesn't occur with the same Xpath as the xsl:message

`<xsl:for-each select="/ACTIS/G01/G07/E2EDT37[E2EDT37_PACK_TYPE='INNER'][E2EDT37_PARENT=$Pallet/E2EDT37_EXIDV][E2EDT37_DELIVERY=$current-delivery][E2EDT37_KDMAT=$current-part]/E2EDT37_VHILM_KU[not(.=preceding::E2EDT37_VHILM_KU)]">`

```
<E2EDT37_VHILM_KU>0000SON</E2EDT37_VHILM_KU>

    No For each E2EDT37_VHILM_KU break on E2EDT37_VHILM_KU=0000SON
```

1) In Create_Outer_PAC Delivery : 0037371519

2) For each Outer_PAC       : 505059227

3) For each E2EDT37_KDMAT   : 6561111

```
<E2EDT37_VHILM_KU>0000SON</E2EDT37_VHILM_KU>

    This one breaks as expected.  You see we have an E2EDT37_VHILM_KU found with value 0000SON in the line above here.
```

I don't reach this message in the first for-each loop above although we also find and display the same E2EDT37_VHILM_KU of 0000SON.

We have two E2EDT37 segments with KDMAT values of 6561143 and 6561141.  The first loop breaks at each unique KDMAT as expected.

4) For each E2EDT37_VHILM_KU    : 0000SON

5) For each E2EDT37_QUANTITY    : 8500.000

Is it valid to check for unique values with /E2EDT37_VHILM_KU[not(.=preceding::E2EDT37_VHILM_KU)] at the same time as limiting the resulting nodes with the predicates [E2EDT37_PACK_TYPE='INNER'][E2EDT37_PARENT=$Pallet/E2EDT37_EXIDV][E2EDT37_DELIVERY=$current-delivery][E2EDT37_KDMAT=$current-part]?  I assume that's where I am wrong but the paradigm is not clear to me.  The message output shows me the Xpath did find a single VHILM_KU.  The next for-each statement with the same Xpath finds nothing.

Is that clearer or more confusing?

Comment: Is *Resulting Output* the desired output? Please show desired output in actual XML format.

Comment: it would also help if you could reduce the example to the minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem - see: [mcve].

Comment: The XML output that would be produced if t he looping worked is not relevant to the question.  And I think the code is trimmed down to what is necessary.  Lets see if I can explain better.